# If conditon showing alert even when the condition is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, alert

I have problem with `if` condition. I write a script who should showing `alert` when value from field `#customer-age` is less than 21 (the calculated age of person). The problem is - the alert is showing every time - when the value is less and greater than 21.

My html code is:

```
<div class="type-text">
<label for="birthday">Date1:</label>
<input type="text" size="20" id="birthday" name="birthday" value="" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div class="type-text">
<span id="customer-age" readonly="readonly"></span>
</div>

<span id="date_from_start">23/11/2012</span>
```

and script looks like:

```
function getAge() {
    var sday =  $('#date_from_start').html();
    var split_date1 = sday.split("/");  
    var todayDate = new Date(split_date1[2],split_date1[1] - 1,split_date1[0]);

    var bday = $('#birthday').val();
    var split_date2 = bday.split("/");
    var birthDate = new Date(split_date2[2],split_date2[1] - 1,split_date2[0]);

    var age = todayDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = todayDate.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && todayDate.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}

var startDate = new Date("1935,01,01");

$('#birthday').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNamesMin: ['Nie', 'Pon', 'Wt', 'Śr', 'Czw', 'Pt', 'Sob'],
    dayNames: ['Niedziela','Poniedzialek','Wtorek','Środa','Czwartek','Piątek','Sobota'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Sty', 'Lut', 'Mar', 'Kwi', 'Maj', 'Cze', 'Lip', 'Sie', 'Wrz', 'Paź', 'Lis', 'Gru'],    
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    constrainInput: true, firstDay: 1, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    yearRange: '-77:-18',
    defaultDate: startDate,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#customer-age').html(getAge(new Date(dateText)));
        var cage = $('#customer-age').val();
          if (cage < 21)
             {
             alert('< 21 year');
             }
          else {
          }
    },
    maxDate: +0
});
```

The workin code you can check on http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/DmYBt/

Comment: People have already pointed out answers but I wanted to quickly say you don't need to pass `new Date(dateText)` to your `getAge` function because your function is pulling it straight from the page via JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your line from:

```
var cage = $('#customer-age').val();
```

to

```
var cage = parseInt($('#customer-age').html(), 10);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DmYBt/4/)

Added:
do you mean like:

```
var infoContent = $.trim( $("#info").html() );
alert( infoContent );
```

Comment: parseInt is not necessary, the type is coerced automatically.

Comment: Maybe you know how to insert a text from `#info` field to the `alert` field?

Comment: @Adrian you should accept this answer to indicate that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is not valid on a span tag and does not return anything.

Use `.html()` instead. `.text()` would also work.

You don't need to parse it explicitely to Int, that is done automatically.

```
var cage = $('#customer-age').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
var cage = $('#customer-age').text();
```

instead of:

```
var cage = $('#customer-age').val();
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DmYBt/6/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the condition, the bug is I think in your date picker.

change you code to this, see what I mean:

```
  if (cage < 21)
  {
     alert(cage);
  }
  else 
  {
  }
```

the value of the variable **cage** is empty. that would be NaN.

Comment: Empty String and `NaN` are different things, `'' < 21` is always true, while comparing `NaN` to a number always yields false except for the `!=` comparison!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You are comparing strings, you should use `parseInt()` to convert to integer and then compare.
2. `cage` is empty;